# Normalize (map) JSON response in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, normalize

I have an object that I'm retrieving via `request` that I need to map over and normalize to an expected response:

`address_list = list(map(normalize_shipping_address, address_list))`

I was hoping to be able to set up some sort of dict to handle the mapping such as:

```
def normalize_shipping_address(address):

    normalized_address = {}

    valueMapping = {
        'firstname': 'firstName',
        'lastname': 'lastName',
        'city': 'city',
        'postcode': 'zip',
        'countryId': 'country',
        'defaultShipping': 'isDefault',
    }

    for source_key, destination_key in valueMapping.iteritems():
        try:
            key = address[source_key]
        except KeyError:
            key = None
        normalized_address[destination_key] = key

    return normalized_address
```

but realized there is not a good way for me to get nested dictionary keys or list objects such as: `address.some.nested.key` or `address.some.list[0].key`.

I ended up handling these special "cases" by doing things such as:

```
try:
    state = address['region']['regionCode']
except KeyError:
    state = None
normalized_address['state'] = state
```

and

```
try:
    address_name = address['customAttributes'][0]['value']
except KeyError:
    address_name = None
normalized_address['addressName'] = address_name
```

This seems a bit verbose and clunky. Is there a more elegant way to parse/normalize dictionaries like this?

Comment: You can define the valueMapping dictionary outside the function that you are mapping

Comment: You can use the `get` function: `normalized_address[key] = address.get(key1).get(key2)`